# How to convert JS Object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Is it posible to convert a js object to json or is a js object exactly a JSON ? Can someone tell me what a JSON exactly is ?

Comment: Click on the `json` tag. Then click on "learn more".

Comment: No. JSON is data-only. You cannot convert a JS "code" object to a JSON object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quite literally, JSON is a stricter format for what is basically the right-hand side of a Javascript variable assignment. It's a text-based encoding of Javascript data:

```
var foo = ...json goes here ...;
```

JSON can be **ANY** valid Javascript data-only structure. A boolean, an int, a string, even arrays and objects. What JSON **ISN'T** is a general serialization format. Something like this

```
var foo = new Date();
json = JSON.stringify(foo); // json gets the string "2016-08-26 etc..."
newfoo = JSON.parse(json);  // newfoo is now a string, NOT a "Date" object.
```

will not work. The Date object will get serialized to a JSON string, but deserializing the string does NOT give you a `Date` object again. It'll just be a string.

JSON can only represent DATA, not CODE. That includes expressions

```
var foo = 2; // "2" is valid json
var foo = 1+1; // invalid - json does not have expressions.
var foo = {"bar":["baz"]}; // also valid JSON
var foo = [1,2,3+4]; // fails - 3+4 is an expression
```

Comment: what problem with var foo = new Date(); json = JSON.stringify(foo); ?

Comment: because `foo` is a Date object, which is code+data. JSON can NOT represent code. While maybe that's ab ad example, because Date objects can be serialized down to a string date by JSON.stringify(), it's just an example. When you json decode that date, you don't get a Date object back, you just have a string.

Comment: ohaky !! thanx :)

Answer (score -4):

To convert JS data object to JSON , you can use  `JSON.stringify()`

**Exmaple**

Input :-

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
JSON.stringify(person)
```

Output:

```
"{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","age":50,"eyeColor":"blue"}"
```

Comment: This converts to string, not JSON.